# What does によせて mean in 『そして誰もいなくなった』によせて

Tags: grammar

> 『そして誰もいなくなった』によせて

It is the beginning of a book of the same name.

What does によせて mean in this sentence?

Comment: Is it not a section title? As opposed to a sentence.

Comment: Yes, i think it is.

Answer (score 6):

Xに寄せて【よせて】 used in a title typically just means "(My Thoughts) Regarding X" or "In Response to X".

The verb is [寄せる](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%AF%84%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B) ("to make something closer"), which is used both in physical and in psychological senses. For example, 彼女に恋心を寄せる means "to direct romantic feelings towards her" (literally) or "to have feelings for her" (naturally). Likewise, Xに寄せて is used in the title of a commentary or formal message that expresses the author's feelings toward a specific topic or event.

Comment: Oh, now i understand. Thank you! :))

Answer (score 1):

よせて is てform of 寄せる。
It simply means "sending the following words to the book of 『そして誰もいなくなった』"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this was the Japanese title given to [Mathew Prichard's short essay](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=G2u6WnHEQQAC&newbks=0&printsec=frontcover&pg=PT5&dq=%22%E3%80%8E%E3%81%9D%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E8%AA%B0%E3%82%82%E3%81%84%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%80%8F%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%81%9B%E3%81%A6%22&hl=en&source=newbks_fb&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22%E3%80%8E%E3%81%9D%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E8%AA%B0%E3%82%82%E3%81%84%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%80%8F%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%81%9B%E3%81%A6%22&f=false) published as the front matter to Agatha Christie's book そして誰もいなくなった (*And Then There Were None*), when it was republished in 2010 in Japanese. The essay was probably written in English first, but was not published in English, I believe.

Back to the question, 寄せる can be used to refer to the act of contributing a work to a publication, as seen in the following examples:

https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000320/files/2168_42800.html

> 予等は旅中の見聞記を毎月幾回か東京朝日新聞に**寄せ**ねばならぬ義務があつた。 (contribution to a newspaper)

https://www.dailyshincho.jp/article/2017/01201940/

> シャ乱Ｑのボーカルで音楽プロデューサーのつんく♂が18日発売の「新潮45」2月号に**寄せ**た手記が大きな反響を呼んでいる。 (contribution to a magazine)

I feel like the usage is derived from originally Chinese terms such as 寄稿 and 寄書. (This is just a guess.) The term 寄稿 is common in Japanese today. 寄書 is less so.